# Sobel and Prewitt operators decomposition

Tags: image-processing, filters, digital-filters

I was reading in the wikipedia page of [Sobel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) and [Prewitt operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator) that is possible to decompose these two operators (quote form the Formulation paragraph):

> "as the products of an averaging and a differentiation kernel, they compute the gradient with smoothing."

I know that this means that I can rewrite and simplify a Prewitt mask (for example) in this way:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 
+1 & 0 & -1 \\
+1 & 0 & -1 \\
+1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
+1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

But I don't understand what are in these cases the averaging and the differentiation kernel? And, why it is written that they can compute the gradient with smoothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part:
\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
acts on vertical pixels 
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_{1,\cdot}\\
x_{2,\cdot}\\
x_{3,\cdot}
\end{bmatrix}
as a weighted sum with equal weights, and if divided by $3$ like a 3-point average $(x_{1,\cdot}+x_{2,\cdot}+x_{3,\cdot})/3$.

Then, 
\begin{bmatrix}
+1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
acts on a row of horizontal pixels 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{\cdot,1}&
x_{\cdot,2}&
x_{\cdot,3}
\end{bmatrix}
like the discrete 3-point derivative: $(x_{\cdot,1}-x_{\cdot,3})/2$ up to the $2$ factor. Here, up to a global $6$ factor, it acts like a smoother vertically combined with a gradient horizontally. The same reasoning works when you switch directions. This notion relates to the separability of a 2D mask into the product of two 1D operators.

Additional sources:

- [What's logic behind the constuction of Sobel's filter in image processing?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/52132/15892)
- [How to find out if a transform matrix is separable?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35296/15892)

Comment: You are welcome. I have added two links if you want to go further with Sobel masks [What's logic behind the constuction of Sobel's filter in image processing?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/52132/15892) and separability [How to find out if a transform matrix is separable?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35296/15892)